Electron app breaks, but only when I don't pull scripts from a CDN
I have an Electron (Vite, JavaScript, Linux) app that imports MathQuill and its dependency, jQuery. In development mode (npm run start), everything works fine. But, if I package my app (npm run package && out/.../copyquill, it breaks, only when I fetch jQuery from a local file.
Specifically, I get this error from somewhere in my JS bundle: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype').
I have a stripped down version of the app at b44ken/copyquill (branch local), but my index.html is something like:
<head>
  <!-- local, broken --> <!-- <script type="module" src="include/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- cdn, works fine --> <script type="module" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="module" src="include/mathquill.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="/src/renderer.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/mathquill.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="field"></div>
</body>

Note the CDN versus local commented lines. My JavaScript (renderer.js) is just:
const MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2)
MQ.MathField(document.querySelector('.field'))

